# How to end-to-end test an Apache Camel Route with SEDA included?

Tags: java, apache-camel, quarkus, seda

I am writing an end-to-end test for my quarkus application that is using Apache Camel. I am basically receiving a message from a URI and sending it to a seda route with multiple consumers. This all works fine in production.

But when I am running my test to see whether the SEDA endpoint got a message, the log shows me

```
2023-11-06 15:02:25,858 INFO  [org.apa.cam.tes.jun.CamelTestSupport] (main) ********************************************************************************
2023-11-06 15:02:25,858 INFO  [org.apa.cam.tes.jun.CamelTestSupport] (main) Testing done: checkSedaForwarding() (com.example[......])
2023-11-06 15:02:25,858 INFO  [org.apa.cam.tes.jun.CamelTestSupport] (main) Took: 48ms (48 millis)
2023-11-06 15:02:25,858 INFO  [org.apa.cam.tes.jun.CamelTestSupport] (main) ********************************************************************************
2023-11-06 15:02:26,601 INFO  [com.get.not.not.LogNotificationSender] (Camel (camel-1) thread #4 - seda://EXAMPLE_ROUTE) Message: [com.google.firebase.messaging.Message@39fa3316] captured
2023-11-06 15:02:26,601 INFO  [com.get.not.mes.han.ExampleRouteHandler] (Camel (camel-1) thread #4 - seda://EXAMPLE_ROUTE) Push notification [com.google.firebase.messaging.Message@39fa3316] got sent out successfully with response:
 {
     "name":"projects/example/messages/0:1500415314455276%31bd1c9631bd1c96"
}
2023-11-06 15:02:35,864 WARN  [org.apa.cam.com.moc.MockEndpoint] (main) The latch did not reach 0 within the specified time
```

and the test fails, even though I can see that the desired handler got called. My test looks like this:

```
    @Test
    public void checkSedaForwarding() throws Exception {

    var eventString = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("src/test/resources/testEvent.json")));
    getMockEndpoint("mock:seda:EXAMPLE_ROUTE").expectedMessageCount(1);


    template.sendBody("direct:example-route", eventString);

    Mockito.verify(exampleRouteHandler, Mockito.times(1)).handle(Mockito.any()); // doesn't get detected
    MockEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied(context);

    Assertions.assertNotNull(context.hasEndpoint("mock:direct:example-route"));
    Assertions.assertNotNull(context.hasEndpoint("mock:seda:EXAMPLE_ROUTE"));
Assertions.assertNotNull(context.hasEndpoint("direct:example-route"));
        Assertions.assertNotNull(context.hasEndpoint("seda:EXAMPLE_ROUTE"));
    }
```

I assume it has something to do with multithreading, as it says something with `thread #4`. I don't know, why the test is not waiting for the event to arrive at the seda endpoint.

I already tried increasing the timeout time, didn't help.

Thanks in advance for any help!